# How to preserve Table Headers during drop down change?

Tags: angularjs

When i am changing Drop down value , the headers of drop down are being lost

The drop down names are all dynamic and should be picked up from JSON only . 
Right now at a time it is displaying only one drop down name .

This is my code

```
   <table border="1">
      <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)>=0">
               <select ng-change="getchange(selectItem)" ng-model="selectItem.selectItem" >
                 <option selected disabled>{{key}}</option>
                  <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{k}}">{{k}}</option>
               </select>
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)<0">
            {{ key }}
            </span>
         </th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in collectioninfo">
         <td ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in row">
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)>=0">
            <!-- {{ getFirstKeyOfDropDown(val2) }} -->
            {{val2[0][selectItem.selectItem] || getFirstKeyOfDropDown(val2)}}
            </span>
            <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)<0">
            {{ val2 }}
            </span>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h6atm89o/16/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save each dropdownlist's selectedItem in a specific field base on the current `key` of `ng-repeat`.

```
<!-- save selectedItem in specific field -->
<select ng-change="getchange(selectItem)" ng-model="selectItem[key]" >

<!-- display value based on value kept in selectItem -->
val2[0][selectItem[key2]]
```

refer the below [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfrsyrwa/2/).

Comment: Thanks , but initially it is empty , can we make it to display headers ?

Comment: when initialize , the first drop down values (Which are in disbaled mode)

Comment: @Kiran I have used es6 new features. if your browser doesn't support it, you may have to create the json in another way. :)

Comment: perfect answer .

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for the help , tested this , right now there are only 2 dropdowns for which it is  working fine , but in case if there are many drop downs the header for them is shown empty , can we make that dynamic ?

Comment: for example i have added a another drop down in this below fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jfrsyrwa/3/

Comment: @Kiran you can use `allkeys.forEach` to create `selectItem` by looping through `allkeys`.